# Generic foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, generics, foreach

The compiler, given the following code, tells me "Use of unassigned local variable 'x'."  Any thoughts?

```
public delegate Y Function<X,Y>(X x);

public class Map<X,Y>
{
    private Function<X,Y> F;

    public Map(Function f)
    {
        F = f;
    }

    public Collection<Y> Over(Collection<X> xs){
        List<Y> ys = new List<Y>();
        foreach (X x in xs)
        {
            X x2 = x;//ys.Add(F(x));
        }
        return ys;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire error?  And is this the real code?

Comment: Also, what version of .Net are you using?

Comment: After fixing the other errors in the code, I don't get that error. What does your code actually look like?

Comment: Shouldn't your constructor take an argument of type `Function<X, Y>` not Function?

Comment: Just wondering, but why would you ever need a class like this? Are you on an old version of .NET?

Comment: I hope that you are using capital X and lowercase x here just for StackOverflow.com question-asking purposes.  X and x in real code makes it hard to follow, among other issues.

Comment: It's also helpful if you tell what line the error appears on.

Comment: @Neil N: `foreach(T t in ...)` is a valid C# idiom. Stylistically, the code is fine except for the inconsistent use of brace placement (Java-style braces on the `Over` method, C#-style braces used everywhere else).

Comment: @Juliet: do the newer libraries already provide this functionality?

Comment: @mcoolbeth - check out `Enumerable.Select` and the `Func` delegate type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After fixing the obvious errors it compiles fine for me.

```
public delegate Y Function<X,Y>(X x);

public class Map<X,Y>
{
    private Function<X,Y> F;

    public Map(Function<X,Y> f)
    {
        F = f;
    }

    public ICollection<Y> Over(ICollection<X> xs){
        List<Y> ys = new List<Y>();
        foreach (X x in xs)
        {
            X x2 = x;//ys.Add(F(x));
        }
        return ys;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The language specification defines `foreach` statement as the equivalent of a `while` loop, in which the loop variable is assigned to the `Current` property of the enumerator object. This definitely satisfies the definite assignment rules of any conforming C# compiler for that code snippet. Either you're using a non-conforming compiler or the error is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This: `public Map(Function f)`

Should be:

```
public Map(Function<X,Y> f)
```

And this:

```
public Collection<Y> Over(Collection<X> xs)
```

Should be:

```
public ICollection<Y> Over(ICollection<X> xs)
```

Or:

```
public List<Y> Over(Collection<X> xs)
```

Comment: or IEnumerable<Y> then you can toss the list and replace the `.Add(...)` with `yield return ...`